# Wordpress get_next_post set the category

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible in Wordpress to set the category used in get_next_post.

I have post that can have more than one category.

On the single.php page showing the post I want to show next and prev posts.

I have the category I want to choose from on the single.php so how do I use that in get_next_post

```
    $the_cat = 'latest';

    $next_post = get_next_post($in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = $the_cat);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see the documentation no.

> $taxonomy
>   (string) (optional) Taxonomy, if $in_same_term is true. Added in WordPress 3.8.
>   Default: 'category'

As I see, if you set the `$in_same_term` to false, then you can change the `$taxonmy`.

I think, it could be a workaround for you, not tested, just an idea:

```
<?php
while ($next_post = get_next_post()) {
    if (!empty($next_post) && $next_post->catID == 'what you want') {
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a>    
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on what it says in the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post...

Within your page loop...

```
$category = get_the_category();
$category_name = $category[0]->name:
```

And then get your next post via...

```
$next_post = get_next_post(true, null, $category_name);
```